# 文字列からscreen_nameだけを取得する

Tags: python, python3

ツイートからRTのみのアカウントを取得したいです。

下記の方法でRTと空白のみを削除するようにしましたが、@mikipddw2on11の文字だけ取得するにはどのように設定すればよろしいでしょうか？   
＊ツイート

RT @mikipddw2on11: 今日の天気 #PR https://t.covIC68vSr4545

*RT @mikipddw2on11:の文字から始まりますが、別のツイートからRTがない場合
今日の天気から文字はじめます。

**コード**

```
 a = tweet.text.replace('\n','').replace('RT ','').replace(':','').split(' ')[0]
```

**結果**

```
['RT @mikipddw2on11']
```

Answer (score 1):

@mikipddw2on11 の部分を正規表現でマッチさせる方法があります。たとえば「`@`から始まって`:`で終わる最初の部分」としてマッチさせるのは如何でしょうか。

```
import re

content1 = "RT @examplename: 今日の天気"
content2 = "今日の天気"
pattern = re.compile('^RT (@[^:]+):')

result1 = pattern.match(content1)

if result1:
    print(result1.group(1))
else:
    print("リツイートではないです")

result2 = pattern.match(content2)

if result2:
    print(result2.group(1))
else:
    print("リツイートではないです")
```

出力

```
@examplename
リツイートではないです
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。

Comment: 毎回違う文字列”今日の天気”ではない場合、どのように設定すれば、よろしいでしょうか。

Comment: 「RT @screen_name: ほにゃらら」形式であればこれで対応できます。一度、正規表現について調べてみてください。「正規表現とは」とか「python 正規表現」とかで検索すると良いです。あるいは、分からない点についてコメントや質問で投稿して頂ければ答えられます :)

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。

Comment: 上記の方法でできませんでした。新規で質問しました。お手隙の際にご確認おねがします。
新規質問件名：文字列からアカウントだけを取得する

Answer (score 1):

tweetがどんなデータ形式かわからないので、正確な答えは返せないかも知れないです。

公式のTwitterのドキュメントから想像して答えます。[Tweet Object](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/intro-to-tweet-json#retweet)
質問者さんのtweetにはリンク先のjsonデータが代入されていると仮定します。
そうすると以下でとれるのではないでしょうか？

```py
json_obj['tweet']['retweeted_status']['user']['screen_name']
```

User Objectのドキュメントを見ると、screen_nameは@の後ろに対応しているみたいです。[User Object](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/user-object)

もしtweet.textから取りたいのであれば、split関数を使うのが楽だと思います

```py
tweet.text.split(' ')[1][1:]
```