# 文字列からアカウントだけを取得する

Tags: python, python3

### 実装したい内容

CSVで書き込んだ（`tweet.text`）から取得した`text`のツイートを`@mikipddw2on11`のみ取得したいです。

#### ツイート（text）

```
RT @mikipddw2on11: 今日の天気 #PR https://t.covIC68vSr4545
```

`RT @mikipddw2on11:`の文字から始まりますが、別のツイートからRTがない場合
`今日の天気`から文字はじめます。
取得したいのは、`@mikipddw2on11`のみだけです。
文字列は毎回異なりますが、RTがない場合、セルを空白にしたいです。

### 実装とエラー

他の方から[別の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/59622/19110)にて正規表現でマッチさせる方法があると教えていただきましたが、

下記の２パターンの方法でやってみましたが、下記のようにエラーが表示されます。

コード①

```
import tweepy
import csv
import re

consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_key = ""
access_secret = ""

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

#ツイート取得
tweet_data = []
data = api.get_user

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,screen_name = "ID",exclude_replies = True).items():
    tweet_data.append([tweet.id,tweet.user.screen_name,tweet.created_at,tweet.text.replace('\n',''),tweet.favorite_count,tweet.retweet_count])

    pattern = re.compile(r"^RT (@(\w){1,15})")
    def get_username(tweet.text):
    for x in pattern.finditer(tweet.text):
        return x.group(1)

#csv出力
with open('tweets.csv', 'w',newline='',encoding='utf-8_sig') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow(["user_id","username","created_at","text","fav","RT"])
    writer.writerows(tweet_data)

    df["text"] = [get_username(x) for x in df["retweet_count"]]
    df.to_csv("test_out.csv", index=False)

pass
```

エラー内容①

```
File "im.py", line 23
    for x in regex.finditer(tweet.text):
      ^
```

[別の方法②](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/59622/%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%88%97%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89screen-name%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91%E3%82%92%E5%8F%96%E5%BE%97%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/59623?noredirect=1#comment64323_59623)でもやってみましたが、

コード

```
・・・省略

    pattern = re.compile(r"^RT (@(\w){1,15})")
    result1 = pattern.match(tweet.text)

#csv出力
with open('tweets.csv', 'w',newline='',encoding='utf-8_sig') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow(["user_id","username","created_at","text","fav","RT"])
    writer.writerows(tweet_data)
```

方法②はエラー表示されませんが、`tweet.text`の列`text`にはRTのアカウントはないです。

長文で失礼いたしました。
もし分かる方いれば教えていただけますでしょうか？
お手数ですがよろしくお願いします。

Comment: [前回の回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/59625/36129)は試してもらえましたでしょうか？

Comment: 方法2のコードで `result1` に正規表現でマッチした結果が入っているはずなので、この変数をCSVに出力すべきなのではないでしょうか？ / 別質問での回答ではこの変数の値を `if` 文で判定していますが、あなたのコードでは代入したっきりで参照されていません。

Comment: forループの中で関数を定義するべきではありません。さらに、質問に書かれているコードはインデントのルールが間違っています。エラー内容を貼るときは部分的にではなく、全てを貼ってください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. コードの文法自体が間違っている。
2. 関数定義の場所がおかしい。
3. dfが定義されていない。
4. retweet_countはリツイートの数であり、"RT @"を含むテキストではない。

あなたのコードの文法ミスは、インデントの方法に起因するものです。pythonはインデントによってブロックを認識しているため、インデントが間違っているとエラーが出ます。

> File "im.py", line 23
>      for x in regex.finditer(tweet.text):
>        ^

これは明らかにあなたのインデント方法が間違っています。

また、関数定義(defから始まる構文)は、一般的にforループの中には書きません。

さらに、dfはpandasデータフレームで使われる変数名として一般的ですが、あなたのコードにはこれを初期化するコードが存在しません。

加えて、retweet_countという列に対する認識が間違っています。retweet_countはリツイートの回数であり、単なる整数値です。

上記を踏まえて修正したコードは以下です。

```py
import tweepy
import csv
import re
import pandas as pd

pattern = re.compile(r"^RT (@(\w){1,15})")


def get_username(text):
    for x in pattern.finditer(text):
        return x.group(1)


consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_key = ""
access_secret = ""

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

#ツイート取得
tweet_data = []
data = api.get_user

debug = False

for i, tweet in enumerate(
        tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,
                      screen_name="wadainotweetrt",
                      exclude_replies=True).items()):
    tweet_data.append([
        tweet.id, tweet.user.screen_name, tweet.created_at,
        tweet.text.replace('\n', ''), tweet.favorite_count, tweet.retweet_count
    ])
    if i > 30 and debug:
        break

#csv出力
with open('tweets.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8_sig') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow(["user_id", "username", "created_at", "text", "fav", "RT"])
    writer.writerows(tweet_data)

df = pd.read_csv("tweets.csv")
df = df[["text"]]
df["retweet_username"] = [get_username(x) for x in df["text"]]
df.to_csv("./test_out.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: 丁寧に教えてくれてありがとうございました。ただ上記のように実行しましたら、下記のTweepyのエラーでます。

Comment: File "casa.py", line 30, in <module>
    tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,screen_name="id",exclude_replies=True).items()):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/cursor.py", line 49, in __next__
    return self.next()

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/cursor.py", line 197, in next
    self.current_page = self.page_iterator.next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/cursor.py", line 108, in next

Comment: data = self.method(max_id=self.max_id, parser=RawParser(), *self.args, **self.kargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 250, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 234, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
tweepy.error.TweepError: Twitter error response: status code = 400

Comment: status code 400についてドキュメントを読んでください。https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/response-codes ちゃんと認証は行ったでしょうか。consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_key, access_secretは設定しましたか？

Comment: リクエストを送りすぎると制限に引っかかるので注意してください。https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544018/twitter-v1-1-400-bad-request 私がdebug=Falseという変数を用意したのは、これをTrueにすることでリクエストを減らしてテストを行えるようにするためです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。やはり制限がかかっていました。

Comment: df.to_csv("tweets.csv", encoding='utf-8_sig' , index=False)にしましたらCSVの文字化けも解決できました。

Comment: ちなみに今だとCSV２個出力されるので、１個だけに全てデータをまとめたいです。下記の方法で修正しましたが、text 、retweet_usernameのカラムのみになります。

Comment: df = pd.read_csv("tweets.csv")
df = df[["text"]]
df["retweet_username"] = [get_username(x) for x in df["text"]]
df.to_csv("tweets.csv", encoding='utf-8_sig' , index=False)

Comment: EXCELのデータを１個にまとめる為にどのように設定すれば良いですか？もしわかれば、教えていただけますでしょうか？

Comment: これ追加しましたらできました、df = df[["user_id", "username", "created_at","text","fav", "RT"]]

Comment: 色々とありがとうございました。